# How to pass concatMap projection to subscribe next?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

How can I use the concatMap projection in the subscribe.next()?

```js
    private onSomethingChange(): Subscription {
        // somethingChanged is a Subject
        return this.somethingChanged.pipe(
            concatMap(somethingProjection =>
                combineLatest([
                    this.firstObservable(somethingProjection),
                    this.secondObservable()
                ])
            )).subscribe(([firstResponse, secondResponse]) => {
                // I need to use somethingProjection here too
        });
    }
```

I found suggestions to use RxJS `map`, but I haven't found a way to use it correctly:

```js
    private onSomethingChange(): Subscription {
        // somethingChanged is a Subject
        return this.somethingChanged.pipe(
           concatMap(somethingProjection =>
               combineLatest([
                   this.firstObservable(somethingProjection),
                   this.secondObservable()
               ]).pipe(map(([firstResponse, secondResponse]) => [somethingProjection, firstResponse, secondResponse])
           )).subscribe(([somethingProjection, firstResponse, secondResponse]) => {
               // ...
        });
   }
```

In the first code snippet, each item in the subscribe projection is of the correct type. If I replace the projection with just `response`, its type would be `[firstResponseType, secondResponseType]`.
In the second code snippet, each item in the subscribe projection is of type `somethingProjectionType | firstResponseType | secondResponseType`. If I replace the projection with just `response`, its type would be `(somethingProjectionType | firstResponseType | secondResponseType)[]`.
How to pass `somethingProjection` to the subcribe next so that each item in the array descrtion is of the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning an array from the [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator, you have to return an object with the required properties.

You can try something like the following:

```js
private onSomethingChange(): Subscription {
  // somethingChanged is a Subject
  return this.somethingChanged
    .pipe(
      concatMap((somethingProjection) =>
        combineLatest([
          this.firstObservable(somethingProjection),
          this.secondObservable(),
        ]).pipe(
          map(([firstResponse, secondResponse]) => ({
            somethingProjection,
            firstResponse,
            secondResponse,
          }))
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(({ somethingProjection, firstResponse, secondResponse }) => {
      // ...
    });
}
```